# Check two codes and display an other between two lists

Tags: excel

dHi,

I have some work in Excel but I can't manage to work out how to do it.
I have two sheets that contain:
Sheet 1.
CodeA and CodeD

Sheet 2.
CodeB and CodeD

what I have to do is to find out the matching CodeA with CodeB.
I've tried Vlookup but it won't work and i don't now why. I've tried with Tags, both in the same sheet but it still won't work, i keep getting #N/A. The table contains empty cells, and some codes don't have a match.

Is there an other way?

thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vlookup should work:

Vlookup

1. The cell you wish to lookup -  i.e. D2
2. The range of values you wish to search in - A$2:B$6 (Lock the numbers so you can fill down)
3. The number of the column toy wish to return - 1 for A, 2 for B (in this example)
4. false -Makes the match exact.

This is assuming the data matches

N/A should occur if the value cannot be found, you can then filter these etc

Comment: thanks for your reply. i've tried but no success. is there an other way?

Comment: i've found the values manually. most of them. do you have an ideea what could be my problem?

Comment: Try doing the above on a very simple set of data, comparing a list i.e. a,b,c,d,e against a,b,c,f and then refine it to your needs